# If Cell is blank, reference the left cell

Tags: excel, reference, cell

Image for reference:

[image]

If the cell on the right (B1) is blank, I want it to use the data in the left cell (A1).

I have tried:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1), A1, B1)
```

However, this only results in an error.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1), A1, "")
```

This results in a 0.

Comment: `=IF(ISBLANK(B1), A1, B1)` is working for me..  whats the error you get ?

Comment: `=IF(ISBLANK(B1),A1,B1)` this must work. Your cells in `B Column` are not empty. Check those cells contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without VBA: Circular reference problem.
If you want to check that if B column has data then no need to paste the column A data..And if column b is blank then you want the column A data to paste in column B , right?
If that's the scenario then you need to open iterative analysis..For this
Go to File>Options>Formula>Enable iterative analysis.

Comment: Thank you for this. I apologise to everyone I wasn't more clear in my initial question. Yes I wanted column A data to paste into column B, if column B was empty. You've given me some direction to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B1), B1=""), A1, B1)
```